# NEVPNManager.shareManager is shared between app and widget?

Tags: ios, widget, vpn, networkextension, nevpnmanager

I am working on a vpn app which also includes the widget.
I found that NEVPNManager.shareManager are different object when I call in app and widget, so the connection status and configuration is not shared.

How could I get the real shared manager?